# Dynamic response from GraphQL mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo-Client to work with a GraphQL back-end (PHP) and have been having some issues with mutations.

The current set of components I'm working on are a form for user details. The details are fetched and displayed with use of a query and can be edited and saved. When a user saves a check is made to decide which values have been changed and these are sent via a mutation to be updated.

The issue I'm having is I'd only like the data which has been updated to be returned from the mutation, as returning every field that *could* have been updated adds a lot to the response time. Is there a way to dynamically build the mutation to decide which fields are returned?

Heres the mutation in it's current state:

```
const UPDATE_CLIENT = gql`
mutation updateClient( $data: [ClientInput]! ) {
    add_update_clients( data: $data ) {
        id
        ref
        name {
            title
            firstname
            surname
            preferred_name
        }
        gender
        dob
        nhs_number
        email
        telephone {
            number
        }
        mobile {
            number
        }
        region {
            id
            name
        }
        referral_received
        user_aware_of_referral
        referred_for {
          id
          name
        }
        weekly_hours
        contract_date
        service_start_date
        expected_end_date
        service_end_date
        reason_left
        po_number
        accounting_ref
        country_of_birth {
            id
            name
        }
        nationality {
            id
            name
        }
        ni_number
        place_of_birth
        ethnicity {
            id
            name
        }
        first_language {
            id
            name
        }
        religion {
            id
            name
        }
        marital_status
        dependants
        sexual_orientation
        height
        weight
        hair_colour
        eye_colour
    }
}
`;
```

And a small piece of code to submit it

```
const mutation = await client.mutate({
            mutation: UPDATE_CLIENT,
            variables: { data },
            errorPolicy: 'all'
        });
```

But essentially, if I update `dob` then that is the only piece of data I'd like in the response

Answer (score 4):

You can use either `@skip` or `@include` directives to specify fields that should be omitted from the selection set. If you're keeping track of which fields have been updated client-side, you can use those values to create a set of variables to pass to your query.

```
mutation updateClient(
  $data: [ClientInput]!
  $includeGender: Boolean = false
  $includeDob: Boolean = false
  $includeEmail: Boolean = false
  # ... and so on
  ) {
  add_update_clients( data: $data ) {
    gender @include(if: $includeGender)
    dob  @include(if: $includeDob)
    email  @include(if: $includeEmail)
    # ... and so on
  }
}
```

Comment: But i'm guessing there's no way to do this if these values exist within `ClientInput`? As essentially, it's an object filled with the data that needs to be changed i.e. `[ClientInput] = { id: 5, firstname: "john" }` - writing each boolean for a form with 20 values seems like a lot of work and I thought GraphQL was supposed to improve data flow..

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no syntax in the current specification that would support that sort of functionality. Rather than trying to cut down the size of the response, I would either A) improve the performance of the backend or B) utilize [optimistic responses](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/optimistic-ui/) to keep your UI responsive regardless of response speed.